# Mongoid default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, default-scope

I set a default_scope on a model drivent by mongoid.

```
default_scope -> {where(tenant_id: Tenant.current.id)}
```

When i make a find no problem:

```
Student.all
```

returns the students of the current tenant

When i create a student:

```
Student.new.tenant
```

returns nil

```
Student.create
```

doesn't assign current tenant

But if i do:

```
Student.all.new.tenant
```

it works

As well as:

```
Student.scoped.new.tenant
```

Is it a normal behaviour ?

Thx mates

Answer (score 0):

As we speak, this is intended. There's an issue [about this API change request on GitHub](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2218).